# Java streams convert list of objects to required data structure

Tags: java, java-stream

I recently started working on Java streams. Below is the code which I have written. End goal is,
I need to convert list of StreamTestObjects in to Map where key is value in ValueObject and value is
list of itemValue in ItemObject.

My desired output:
{"NA":["USA", "CANADA"], "EU":["FRANCE", "IRELAND"], "AS":["INDIA", "JAPAN"]}

List countries = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("USA", "CANADA", "FRANCE", "IRELAND", "INDIA", "JAPAN", "Germany", "Australia"));

Only if itemValue in ItemObject exists in countries list, Value in Map(desired output) should be build.

I was able to do it with multiple if conditions. I want to do this using Java streams. Please help

```
    public class StreamTestObject {
        private String propertyName;
        private ValueObject valueObject;
        private ItemObject itemObject;
    
        public StreamTestObject(String propertyName, ValueObject valueObject, ItemObject itemObject) {
            this.propertyName = propertyName;
            this.valueObject = valueObject;
            this.itemObject = itemObject;
        }
        public String getPropertyName() {
            return propertyName;
        }
    
        public ValueObject getValueObject() {
            return valueObject;
        }
    
        public ItemObject getItemObject() {
            return itemObject;
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<StreamTestObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            StreamTestObject streamTestObject = new StreamTestObject("test",
                    new ValueObject("json", "NA"), new ItemObject("code", "USA"));
            StreamTestObject streamTestObject1 = new StreamTestObject("test",
                    new ValueObject("json", "NA"), new ItemObject("code", "CANADA"));
            StreamTestObject streamTestObject2 = new StreamTestObject("test",
                    new ValueObject("json", "EU"), new ItemObject("code", "FRANCE"));
            StreamTestObject streamTestObject3 = new StreamTestObject("test",
                    new ValueObject("json", "EU"), new ItemObject("code", "IRELAND"));
            StreamTestObject streamTestObject4 = new StreamTestObject("test",
                    new ValueObject("json", "AS"), new ItemObject("code", "INDIA"));
            StreamTestObject streamTestObject5 = new StreamTestObject("test",
                    new ValueObject("json", "EU"), new ItemObject("code", "JAPAN"));
            arrayList.add(streamTestObject);
            arrayList.add(streamTestObject1);
            arrayList.add(streamTestObject2);
            list<String> countries = 
            arrayList.stream().map(temp -> {
                Map<String, List<String>> regionWiseFcs = new HashMap<>();
                List<String> fcs = new ArrayList<>();
                fcs.add(temp.getItemObject().getItemValue());
                regionWiseFcs.put(temp.getValueObject().getValue(), fcs);
                return regionWiseFcs;
            });
```

```
    public class ValueObject {
        private String type;
        private String value;
    
        public ValueObject(String type, String value) {
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
        }
    //getter methods.
    }
```

```
    public class ItemObject {
        private String itemType;
        private String itemValue;
    
        public ItemObject(String itemType, String itemValue) {
            this.itemType = itemType;
            this.itemValue = itemValue;
        }
    //getter methods
```

Code which I have tried

```
arrayList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StreamTestObject::getValueObject,
                Collectors.mapping(StreamTestObject::getItemObject, Collectors.toSet())));
```

But this didn't give desired result. In Grouping by I am not sure how to pass getValueObject#value. It is only taking getValueObject

Below is the Java code which I have written without using steams.

```
        Map<String, List<String>> testMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> na = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> eu = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> jp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (StreamTestObject streamTest : arrayList) {
            if (streamTest.getValueObject().getValue().equals("NA") && countries.contains(streamTest.getItemObject().getItemValue())) {
                na.add(streamTest.getItemObject().getItemValue());
                testMap.put(streamTest.getValueObject().getValue(), na);
            } else if (streamTest.getValueObject().getValue().equals("EU") && countries.contains(streamTest.getItemObject().getItemValue())) {
                eu.add(streamTest.getItemObject().getItemValue());
                testMap.put(streamTest.getValueObject().getValue(), eu);
            } else if (streamTest.getValueObject().getValue().equals("AS") && countries.contains(streamTest.getItemObject().getItemValue())) {
                jp.add(streamTest.getItemObject().getItemValue());
                testMap.put(streamTest.getValueObject().getValue(), jp);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to be `collect`ing via `groupingBy` using `ValueObject#getValue` while alongside `mapping` the `ItemObject#getItemValue` with `toList`. This shall at least help you try and then come back to ask what didn't work there. So waiting for some debugging details to this question until then.

Comment: @Naman Hi Naman, I tried grouping by ```arrayList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StreamTestObject::getValueObject));```. I am not sure how to group by ValueObject#getValue in above stream

Comment: @Naman I provided all details in code now. Can you check and remove the downvote

Comment: I haven't really downvoted and now that you have tried hands-on using the method reference. It's way easy to identify that lambda representation using `->` is the way to solve for what you are looking for.  e.g. `Collectors.groupingBy(sto -> sto.getValueObject().getValue(),....` and similarily in `mapping`.

Comment: Yep it worked for me, Not sure why I am still seeing "Closed. This question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers." in this question

Comment: Well, there are two ways to it. One, that it is reopened and closed as a duplicate (using a lambda instead of method reference) or we leave it as it is for cleanup and you move ahead with the learnings. If you think, first would be better, I can vote to reopen and then link duplicates. :) Aside, downvotes are not counted once the thread is cleaned up(deleted) from the site.

Comment: Please vote to reopen if you can.

Comment: Alright, did that.

Answer (score 1):

```java
List<String> countries = List.of("USA",
                                 "CANADA",
                                 "FRANCE",
                                 "IRELAND",
                                 "INDIA",
                                 "JAPAN",
                                 "Germany",
                                 "Australia");

Map<String, List<String>> map = arrayList.stream()
                                         .filter(sto -> countries.contains(sto.getItemObject().getItemValue()))
                                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(sto -> sto.getValueObject().getValue(),
                                                                        Collectors.mapping(sto -> sto.getItemObject().getItemValue(),
                                                                                           Collectors.toList())));
```

The first parameter of method [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) is a function that returns the [Map] key.

The second parameter is a [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) that creates the `List` which is the [Map] value.

The first parameter of method `mapping()` is the value of an element in the `List`.

The second parameter is the actual `List`.

Using the code from method `main()`, in your question, the `Map` produced by the above code is:

```
{EU=[FRANCE, IRELAND], AS=[INDIA, JAPAN], NA=[USA, CANADA]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got my mistake. However my use case is, only if country is present in another list I should update the MAP. Eg: In this case only if country is present in ```List countries = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("USA", "CANADA", "FRANCE", "IRELAND", "INDIA", "JAPAN", "Germany", "Australia"));``` I should update the ```{EU=[FRANCE, IRELAND], AS=[INDIA, JAPAN], NA=[USA, CANADA]}```. Can this be done as well using streams?

Comment: ``` Map<String, List<String>> map = arrayList.stream()
                .filter(e -> countries.contains(e.getItemObject().getItemValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(sto -> sto.getValueObject().getValue(),
                        Collectors.mapping(sto -> sto.getItemObject().getItemValue(),
                                Collectors.toList())));
This code worked for me